# Display payment made by mark every 3 month for the last 3 years

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table called payment it has date field, i have a customer called Mark who has been making payment every day for 3 years

```
Table: Payment  
Fields: Name , Amountpaid, date
```

I want to display payment record made by mark every 3 month and also the total  Amountpaid  for 3 years

**How i want the result to look like**

```
First 3 months payment record table
total Amountpaid at the bottom of the table 

second 3 months payment record table
total Amountpaid at the bottom of the table 

Third 3 months payment record table
total Amountpaid at the bottom of the table
```

and so on for 3 years

Please do help out

Comment: What happens if there is a missed payment or extra payment?

Comment: If it was me, for the purposes of the question, I'd simplify the requirement (3 days instead of 3 years, say), and see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you're looking for a SQL solution for this, but databases are for holding data, they aren't for formatting it into a report. To this end my advice would be: Don't try and do this in the database, do it in the front end code instead

It will be very simple to run a query like

```
SELECT * FROM payment WHERE 
  name = 'mark' and 
  `date` between date_sub(now(), interval 3 year) and now()
ORDER BY date
```

And then put the results into an HTML table usig a loop, and a variable that keeps track of the amount paid total. Every 3 months reset the variable. If you want MySQL to do a bit more data processing to help out you can do this:

```
SELECT * FROM 
  payment 
  INNER JOIN
  (SELECT YEAR(`date`) + (QUARTER(`date`)/10) as qd, SUM(amountpaid) as qp FROM payment WHERE name = 'mark' GROUP BY YEAR(`date`), QUARTER(`date`)) qpt 
  ON
    qpt.qd = YEAR(`date`) + (QUARTER(`date`)/10)
WHERE 
  name = 'mark' AND
  `date` between date_sub(now(), interval 3 year) and now()
ORDER BY `date`
```

This will give all mark's data row by row and an extra two columns (that mostly repeat themselves over and over) showing the year and quarter (3 months) of the year like 2017.1, 2017.2, together with a sum of all payments made in that quarter. Formatting it in the front end now won't need a variable to keep a running total of the amount paid

This is about the limit of what you should do with formatting the data in the database (personal opinion). If, however, you're determined to have MySQL do pretty much all this, read on..

Ysth mentioned rollup, which is intended for summarising data.. such a solution would look like this:

```
SELECT
  Name, `date`, SUM(amountpaid) as amountpaid
FROM
  payment
WHERE 
  name = 'mark' AND
  `date` between date_sub(now(), interval 3 year) and now()
GROUP BY
  name,
  YEAR(`date`) + (QUARTER(`date`)/10),
  `date`
WITH ROLLUP
```

The only downside with this approach is you also get a totals row for all payments by mark. To suppress that, use grouping sets instead:

```
SELECT
  Name, `date`, SUM(amountpaid) as amountpaid
FROM
  payment
WHERE 
  name = 'mark' AND
  `date` between date_sub(now(), interval 3 year) and now()
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS 
(
 (
  name,
  YEAR(`date`) + (QUARTER(`date`)/10),
  `date`
 ),
 (
  name,
  YEAR(`date`) + (QUARTER(`date`)/10)
 )
)
```

Comment: BTW, date is NOT a reserved word

Comment: Noted for future, however misled I was this time - the backticks shouldn't hurt, and I already spent long enough on an iPad editing them in, I'll pass on editing them back out again :) (using SO on an ipad is a fairly horrendous experience, particularly with trying to position the cursor accurately, and selecting text accurately near impossible). I suppose I could revert the edit as one quick way..

Answer (score 1):

You can use a group by on the year and month divided by 3 and truncated using floor

```
SELECT
  EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM `date`),
  SUM(`Amountpaid`)
FROM
  `Payment`
WHERE
      `Name` = 'Mark'
  AND `date` >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 3 YEAR)
GROUP BY
  EXTRACT(YEAR FROM `date`),
  FLOOR(EXTRACT(MONTH FROM `date`) / 3)
```

For the total you will need to iterate the result set and sum up the amounts paid, or if you want it as the final record you could do a `UNION SELECT` but this would be ineffecient, but for completeness it is below:

```
SELECT
  EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM `date`),
  SUM(`Amountpaid`)
FROM
  `Payment`
WHERE
      `Name` = 'Mark'
  AND `date` >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 3 YEAR)
GROUP BY
  EXTRACT(YEAR FROM `date`),
  FLOOR(EXTRACT(MONTH FROM `date`) / 3)
UNION SELECT
  NULL,
  SUM(`Amountpaid`)
FROM
  `Payment`
WHERE
      `Name` = 'Mark'
  AND `date` >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 3 YEAR)
```

Comment: With a group by, you want to select sum(amountpaid), not amountpaid.

Comment: Also you don't want to mod 3, as this will cause Jan + Apr + Jul + oct, Feb + may + Aug + nov etc when what you want is Jan + Feb + mar, Apr + may + Jun etc

Comment: Sort of, you'd need to group by quarter then by day if you wanted rollup to work

Comment: I thought I might have to.. I write most of my SO answer queries just straight out of my head, on an iPad, and putting back ticks in is a pain in the arse on an iPad..

Answer (score 0):

This is for get summary per 3 months :

```
select year(date)*100+floor(month(date)/3) as period, sum(amountpaid)
from payment
where name = 'mark' and (date between '2014-01-01' and '2017-01-01')
group by year(date)*100+floor(month(date)/3)
order by period
```

And this is how to get summary 3 year :

```
select sum(amountpaid) from payment where name = 'mark' and (date between '2014-01-01' and '2017-01-01')
```

You can change the date `between` for your need

Comment: Few problems with this solution: your second query doesn't select just mark, and you passed your dates in as strings. You should always do some effort to convert your strings to dates, e.g. `SELECT * FROM table WHERE datecol > STR_TO_DATE('20170101' '%Y%m%d')`

Comment: @CaiusJard : Can you tell me the reason why must convert it to date? Because most of my queries in online products now using that kind of query

Comment: It makes absolutely sure of 2 things.. 1) that the database will convert your two parameter strings to dates then search your million rows of dates without converting the data at all, rather than convert a million rows of dates to strings then do comparison on strings (this also causes indexes to be disabled), and 2) that the conversion from date to string is accurate: if I write '01/04/2014' is that first of April or fourth of January?

Comment: Most people argue against these points with stuff like "well I never had a problem" or "MySQL always seems to guess the date conversion correctly" but ultimately if you wouldn't write `SELECT strName, intAge FROM person WHERE intAge = '27'` i.e. Passing the age integer in as a string, then you shouldn't write `SELECT strName, dtBirthdate FROM tblPerson WHERE dtBirthdate = '2016.01.01'` just because there isn't a way in most rdbms to write "a date as a date". Microsoft Access is a bit of an exception actually, it supports dates surrounded by # and parses them as dates, e.g. #2017/1/1#

Comment: @CaiusJard : I've try looking for articles that described your reason and found nothing until now, and I find most of answers in this so using my format. Do you have any valid resources for your statements?

Comment: So when you're searching a database table column full of ints, you pass those as strings too?  Be honest now, do you write `SELECT strName, intAge FROM person WHERE intAge = '27'` or do you write `SELECT strName, intAge FROM person WHERE intAge = 27` ?

Comment: @CaiusJard : I'm sure you are stated about date at beginning, I don't know you are testing me or something, but I'm sure we know that for integer you no need to put `'` mark.

Comment: I'm not testing you, I'm trying to get you to think for a second. Right, so if you wouldnt pass an integer as a string like '27', why do you pass a date as a string? To a computer, '2017/01/01' or '01-Jan-2017' aren't dates, they're strings, just like 'first of Jan twenty seventeen' is.. the DB has to do some effort to convert these strings to a date, just like it has to do something to convert '27' to an integer. So why do we have to write dates as strings? Because (apart from Microsoft Access) there isn't a way to write a date as a date.. I'm saying you should explicitly convert your string

Comment: I'll try to make the point another way: in Microsoft access you can write `SELECT * FROM tblPerson WHERE dtBirthdate = #32-Jan-2017#` and the query will fail because there is no 32 of January, and to Access, anything surrounded by #hashes# should certainly be parsed to a date. In some other database, you might write `SELECT * FROM tblPerson WHERE dtBirthdate = '32-Jan-2017'`, the DB doesn't try converting '32-Jan-2017' to a date, instead it converts every birthdate of a million rows, from date, to string and then compares the strings. This wastes resources and disables indexes

Comment: @CaiusJard : Because it is writed as example here https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/using-date.html and https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-literals.html

Show me your reference not just your opinion.

Comment: I'm not certain I need to use my opinion, I can just use yours (unless you don't know what a datatype is, don't know what strong typing is, don't know the difference between a numerical string and a number). The basic problem is, you're here teaching others and you have a responsibility to do it well. Someone might read your query, which might even work properly thanks to date string being in some certain format, and he'll write query with date in a different format ('mm/dd/yyy') and it won't work out, because server parses dd/mm/yyyy. I want you to stop looking for some blog/manual and THINK

Comment: @CaiusJard : I'm not sure you have read the link or not but don't make other confusion with your statement's. Here opening from my link provided above `The format of a DATE value is 'YYYY-MM-DD'. According to standard SQL, no other format is permitted. As a convenience, MySQL automatically converts a date to a number if the date is used in a numeric context and vice versa.`

Comment: And you think automatic conversion is good, acceptable in all cases and with all education level of users? Being explicit causes no harm, relying on implicit can cause harm. Aside from the fact that we're talking about string<->date, not number<->date, does your magic document tell you exactly which date MySQL will automatically convert for you? Does it convert your string parameter to date, or does it convert a million rows dates to string.. hmm. Be explicit. You write brackets in a maths operation when you could just rely on BODMAS right? With compters, explicit is good, implicit is bad

Comment: Ps; your magic document says `For those exceptions, the comparison is done by converting the objects to strings and performing a string comparison. To be on the safe side, assume that strings are compared as strings and use the appropriate string functions if you want to compare a temporal value to a string.` - danger danger - you've even got the MySQL manual here telling you there are situations where things stored as dates are converted to strings and comparison is done using strings.. i think I can rest my case now. Be explicit!